# Why is my Ruby (2.2.2) using ASCII-8 instead of UTF-8

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii, ruby-2.0

The proximate problem I'm having is that in my app, these errors are happening in a JSON#dump call:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xEF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
```

I'm trying to understanding encoding issues with Ruby better. I read everywhere that as of Ruby 2.0, UTF-8 is the default encoding. Yet I find:

```
 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "2.2.2"
 > __ENCODING__
 => #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

I know the RUBYOPT env variable is one solution, but since I have to coordinate this solution between many developers and a few production & staging servers, I'd really like to fill the holes in my understanding first.

I have a file that the bash utility "file" correctly figures out is utf-8:

```
[none] andrew@~/ws$ file sample.txt
sample.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

But this is not working as expected in ruby.

```
[none] andrew@~/ws$ irb
 > text = File.read("sample.txt")
 => "\xE2\x99\xAA It seems today\nthat all you see \xE2\x99\xAA\n"
 > text.encoding
 => #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

Of course there are numerous manual ways to do it:

```
 > Encoding.default_external = Encoding.list[1]
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
 > text = File.read("sample.txt")
 => "♪ It seems today\nthat all you see ♪\n"
```

But why might I not be getting utf-8 by default? For now I'll likely do something like the above in an initializer, but I'm really hoping to understand what's going on in ruby. Is there some environment variable or setting I should be looking for that I might have missed ($RUBYOPT is blank in my local environment)?

Comment: Is this only happening in irb or when running a Ruby script from the command line? Do you have something in your .irbrc?

Comment: Also when running a ruby script, it seem. Using   $ ruby -e "puts Encoding.default_external"  yields   US-ASCII. However puts'ing the file contents in the script displays the characters correctly, perhaps because the terminal is interpreting it even though ruby is not I think. And the first error in my post is occurring in my Rails server, so definitely not just irb. One step at a time, though...

Comment: FTR, my .irbrc file contains an assignment to IRB.conf[:PROMPT] and IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE], but this is definitely only on my local machine and not on the production server :-)

Comment: UTF-8 is the default encoding for *Ruby source code*, not for I/O. The I/O encodings are usually taken from the encoding you have set up in your OS, I think.

Comment: What does `ENV['LANG']` return? Btw. `File.read("sample.txt", encoding: Encoding::UTF_8)` is simpler and works everywhere.

Comment: ENV['LANG'] == "en_US.UTF-8".I'll start remembering to toss the encoding option into File.read. Guess I thought the Ruby 2 change would mean better auto-detection in File and IO. Hate to say it, but it's the remaining hold-out that makes perl still better for quick one-liner scripts...

Comment: And what about `LC_ALL` and `LC_CTYPE` env vars? I'm also not sure why you did assume Ruby added auto-detection. Is that what Perl does? Or does it just default to UTF-8 (on your system)?

Comment: ENV['LC_ALL'] == "C"; ENV['LC_CTYPE'] == nil; Not familiar with these vars.

Comment: The bash one-liner cat file | perl -ne '/my_patter/ && print', as an example, has not barfed at any text file I've thrown at it. The ruby equivalent, cat file | ruby -ne '$_ =~ /pattern/ and print $_' will raise an exception with the above example text containing the ♪: "invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII", and halt processing. Since such characters are rare, I tend not to notice this is an issue in test data, only finding out when I leave a text processing script running overnight, where it usually fails about 2 minutes after I leave the office.